# Column titles contain sample info how do i split them into two columns in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean up some data frames to a more useful format, I am running R studio 1.3.1093 and R 3.5.3.

My data frame looks like this:

| Peptide | 5C_T6m | 5C_T12m |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PEP | 0.5 | 1.1 |
| TIDE | 0.6 | 1.2 |

and I am trying to convert it to:

| Peptide | Temp | Timepoint | abundance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PEP | 5 | 6 | 0.5 |
| TIDE | 5 | 6 | 0.6 |
| PEP | 5 | 12 | 1.1 |
| TIDE | 5 | 12 | 1.2 |

I can't visualize in my head how it is possible to move between the two. in a stepwise approach.
Im new to R, and have done some bits of data reshaping using TidyVerse, but this seems to me like it requires multiple steps to get there, and its is hard for me to visualise the individual steps.

Any help with either just the steps i would need to take or some code suggestions would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `pivot_longer` is very useful in this kind of cases

```
df %>%  pivot_longer(cols=!Peptide, 
                 names_to = c("Temp", "Timepoint"),
                 names_pattern = "(.*)C_T(.*)m",
                 values_to = "abundance")
```

Comment: I've upvoted because this answer gives a good technical solution.  But it would be an even better answer with an *explanation*, particularly of what `names_pattern` is doing.

Comment: Thanks for this answers, works really nicely. How would i expand the
 Pivot_longer(Cols=!Peptide,  argument to include more columns? say an additional column called "Molecule".  i've tried Pivot_longer(Cols(c(=!Peptide, Molecule), for example but that hasnt worked.

Comment: You have to see  https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html,  you can use different arguments for 'cols'. In that page you can find an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution, as I understood that you wanted.

```
library(tidyverse)
 
 df <- data.frame(Peptide = c("PEP","TIDE"), C5_T6m = c(0.5,0.6), C5_T12m = c(1.1,1.2)) 
 
 dt <- df %>% 
gather( Timepoint, abundance, 2:3) %>% 
mutate(Temp = str_extract(Timepoint,"5")) %>% 
mutate(Timepoint =  str_extract(Timepoint,"6|12")) %>% 
select(Peptide,Temp,Timepoint,abundance)
```

Result

```
>  dt
  Peptide Temp Timepoint abundance
1     PEP    5         6       0.5
2    TIDE    5         6       0.6
3     PEP    5        12       1.1
4    TIDE    5        12       1.2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! it works really well, just like the answer above-- and i can easily edit it to incorporate more timepoints and temps that need gathering. You can change the gather( Timepoint, abundance, 2:3) to incorporate all possible columns to make it more flexible.  I have used gather( Timepoint, abundance, 2:ncol(df)) and that seems to work nicely! thanks for your help

Comment: An issue i have found with this is say when the Temp and Timepoint have the same characters in them for example. if it had temperatures of 5 and 60 and Timepoints of 6 and 12. then the data for Timepoint =12 is listed as  Timpoint =6 . not sure how to get around this... any thoughts?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. Present a data frame to see an example of what you need.   df <- data.frame(Peptide = c(.........

Comment: Sorry, what i mean is if the data frame looks like this:

df <- data.frame(Peptide = c("PEP","TIDE"), C5_T6m = c(0.5,0.6), C60_T12m = c(1.1,1.2))

and the code is updated to the following.:
dt <- df %>% 
  gather( Timepoint, abundance, 2:3) %>% 
  mutate(Temp = str_extract(Timepoint,"5|60")) %>% 
  mutate(Timepoint =  str_extract(Timepoint,"6|12")) %>% 
  select(Peptide,Temp,Timepoint,abundance)

The outputted table does not add the Timepoint = str_extract(Timepoint "6|12")) correctly. I assume it is because of the str_extract command. Im not sure if there is an alternative

Comment: In the code that you pass now, you have replaced the gather function of my code with collec. If you use gather again, it's fine